# Use ESBuild plugins for decorators with NX

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx, esbuild, typescript-decorator

I have created a Node.js project with Typescript with nx using the command

`nx g @nx/node:application [name] --framework none --projectNameAndRootFormat derived`

Here is the build configuration in my project.json:

```
"build": {
  "executor": "@nx/esbuild:esbuild",
  "defaultConfiguration": "production",
  "fileName": "main.js",
  "options": {
    "platform": "node",
    "outputPath": "dist/apps/project-name",
    "format": ["esm"],
    "bundle": true,
    "main": "apps/project-name/src/main.ts",
    "tsConfig": "apps/project-name/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": ["apps/fproject-name/src/assets"],
    "generatePackageJson": true,
    "esbuildOptions": {
      "sourcemap": true,
      "outExtension": {
        ".js": ".js"
      }
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "development": {},
    "production": {
      "esbuildOptions": {
        "sourcemap": false,
        "outExtension": {
          ".js": ".js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The created project uses the NX executor `@nx/esbuild:esbuild`. Now I want to be able to use dependency injection frameworks, such as TypeDI. The problem is that ESBuild does not support the tsconfig property `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` which is required for most dependency injection frameworks for Typescript. There are plugins that can make ESBuild support this such as [esbuild-decorators](https://github.com/anatine/esbuildnx/tree/main/packages/esbuild-decorators).

Previously it seems like it hasn't been possible to add a plugin to ESBuild with NX. However, based on [this issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/15021) and [this PR](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/16092) it seems like it should now be possible. The problem is that I cannot find any documentation on how it is done.

So in summary: How do I add the [esbuild-decorators](https://github.com/anatine/esbuildnx/tree/main/packages/esbuild-decorators) plugin to my NX app running ESBuild?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the fix or not, but you might try these changes: 1) change bundle to `false`, 2) add a `"target": "esnext"` in options? I'm just comparing your code above with what is mostly working for a project I'm working on.

Comment: Are you able to get Typescript decorators and use dependency injection frameworks like TypeDI with those changes?

Comment: we are using decorators and using inversify dependency injection in our nx project with esbuild. I was just trying to see what looked different in this one file

Comment: @FredrikWallén Did you manage to get esbuild-decorators to work?